# DNN7 installer .vsi file for dynamic module not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, c#-4.0, dotnetnuke

I am facing a issue regarding the DDN7 Module installer file ie for adding the components in VS2012 but it i not working for me
I have tried below url insataller file

http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/releases/view/107619

ALso the 
DotNetNuke_Community_07.00.06_StarterKit.vsi kit this is also not working for me

Please help me ASAP thanks in adavnce

Comment: -1 for "ASAP" at least and "not working" usually isn't something valid to be called "error description". And instead of flagging vb.net and c# it should probably be flagged as `visual-studio-2012` - but that might depend on the `error` which of course we dont know.

Comment: I am not getting any error set up file installed succesfully.But it dosn't show any installed components in VS2012.Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the manual installation of the template

https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/releases/view/107802

Grab the ZIP file and put it into the Visual Studio 2012/Templates/Web folder